# Exported runnable .jar File w/ Eclipse using libgdx

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, libgdx, runnable

So my problem is that I want to export my libgdx desktop project as a runnable .jar file. I already made this work and it is working fine when I open the .jar file from my desktop. However, if I put the .jar file into my Dropbox or in any other directory other than my Desktop, it won't work anymore. The Gameframe opens for like 0.2sec, stays black and closes again immediatly. If I then pull the .jar back to my Desktop it works fine.

I've seen other people ask this before, but none of the answers helped me with my problem. 
If you need any more info please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

Try opening the exported JAR in (for example) 7-zip and then adding the 'res' folder manualy. I don't really understand, why Eclipse didn't put the 'res' folder in it. But adding it manualy worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse, make sure to right-click the whole project and click export. In library handling, click on "Package required libraries into generated JAR". Then click finish. If that does not work, make sure your build path includes everything.

Can I have access to the .jar file so I can look what is missing inside it?

Comment: Hi, I just figured out what the problem is using cmd and opening the .jar file from there.  Apparently the error comes because my game is unable to access one of the Assets ( here:  "couldnt load file: img/moos.jpg").  It worked on the desktop because I had a backup folder of my img/  folder on there. 

I also checked the .jar file with a .rar reader and saw that there indeed is my img/   folder with all the nessessary Assets in there. 
Am I not allowed to have subfolders in my Assets Folder? I created it in eclipse.

If this doesn't help I can download the .jar file for you, sure.

Comment: EDIT: Fixed it! The error was that in the sourcecode I loaded "image.jpg" when it should have been "image.JPG".  Didnt know that something like this matters this much... Also I wonder why it was no problem when I started the Project inside of Eclipe?

Comment: I don't know, this should not happen. To export my assets in my game, i created a new Source folder, where I put everything (Like maps, images, sounds), so it gets exported automatically with the .jar. I'm sure there i a better way to do this, but until I find it, I'll be working this day. Don't forget to edit the main post to tell which answer you found, there might be other people out there with the same issue as you.

Comment: If you have assets in you Project be sure to mark them as sourcefolder in eclipse. Also make sure you check this files for the Export. Look at http://obviam.net/index.php/getting-started-in-android-game-development-with-libgdx-create-a-working-prototype-in-a-day-tutorial-part-1/ for informations about how to Setup your Project.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you got some additional libraries in your output directory which are missing when you place your jar in dropbox. To confirm this try to start your application via command line. Java will then print a stacktrace with the exception. Example:

java -jar yourjarinthisdirectory.jar

As a side note I would recommend to use maven in the future [maven libgdx](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/MavenProjectSetup). In this case you just can say "package" and maven produces complete jar with all libs inside it without further configuration.